# Javascript object property doesn't return correct length

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, properties

I dynamically clone an element using jQuery and ask an object to return its length, but it returns `1` every time. Please see fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/gatzkerob/x5xd2x7q/3/

```
<span class="count">0</span>
<br>
<button>click</button>
<br>
<span class="a">a</span>

var obj = {
elem : $('.a')
}

function cloneThisAndCount(){
$('.a').last().after($('.a').first().clone());
$('.count').text(obj.elem.length);
}

$('button').click(function(){
cloneThisAndCount();
});
```

Comment: use `$('.count').text($('.a').length);`

Comment: What is expected result?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the relevant code directly in the question body. (As far as your actual problem, nothing in your code updates the `obj` object after it is created.)

Comment: He just doesn't know that the selector result is caching to the property

Comment: I know that I can access directly using `$('.a')` but I want to use properties so I don't have to type long class names every time.

Comment: you need to perform the selector again.. ok.. i have an alternative. ill edit my answer

Comment: @gatzkerob have a look at the 2 possibilities in the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var obj = {
  elem : $('.a')
}
```

will be computed once and cached into `obj.elem` in the begenning. which will be `1`.

Note (thanx to [nnnnn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/615754/nnnnnn)): When you have a reference to a jQuery object it is possible that other code could update that object to add more elements to it.

**SOLUTION 1:**

What you need is to do is, redo the selector every time before calculating length.

```js
function cloneThisAndCount() {
  $('.a').last().after($('.a').first().clone());
  $('.count').text($('.a').length);
}

$('button').click(function() {
  cloneThisAndCount();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="count">0</span>
<br>
<button>click</button>
<br>
<span class="a">a</span>
```

**SOLUTION 2**:

Change `obj` to:

```
var obj = {
  elem : function(){ return $('.a')}
}
```

and then check length like: `$('.count').text(obj.elem().length);`

```js
var obj = {
  elem: function() {
    return $('.a')
  }
}

function cloneThisAndCount() {
  $('.a').last().after($('.a').first().clone());
  $('.count').text(obj.elem().length);
}

$('button').click(function() {
  cloneThisAndCount();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="count">0</span>
<br>
<button>click</button>
<br>
<span class="a">a</span>
```

Comment: Snippet #2 did the trick, cheers. I actually tried that at one stage but didn't add parenthesis after "elem".

Comment: *"which will be 1."* - Note that when you have a reference to a jQuery object it is possible that other code could update that object to add more elements to it. (But as you've said, it doesn't automatically update itself to include elements later added to the DOM.)

Comment: Cool. Of course (as usual) I'm being overly pedantic, because the vast majority of jQuery methods return a new object without changing the old one so 99% of the time it's not a problem, but there are ways to change an existing jQuery object, e.g., `$.merge(obj.elem, $("p"))`.

Comment: is there any reason for the behaviour?

Comment: some being updated, while others don't . -  Assuming in the merge example `$('p')` was updated.

Comment: @Iceman I'm curious about that too. If I change the value of an existing element, say an `<input>`, the object property will return the updated value just fine without using `function(){ return x;}` But as we saw earlier, it won't return additional elements added to the DOM. Would like to know why.

Comment: u mean like `.val()`?

Comment: its a function. it recomputes. like in soln 2

Comment: @gatzkerob - The `$("a selector")` function returns a new jQuery object that contains references to the specific set of DOM elements that matched the selector *at that moment*. This set is *not* updated if you add more elements to the DOM that match that selector, nor are elements removed from the jQuery object if those elements are updated such that they no longer match the selector. Note that it is posslble to create a jQuery object via methods that don't use string-based selectors.

Comment: *(continued...)* So the `.length` property will always work in the sense of correctly reporting how many DOM element references are in the jQuery object, but this is highly unlikely to change since you'd have to deliberately change it via something like `$.merge()`.  Methods like `.val()` retrieve current properties from whatever DOM element(s) are in the jQuery object (these property values are not stored in the jQuery object).